# backspace and return not working in android standalone app developed in livecode

Tags: livecode

The backspace and return key works fine in my desktop version of an app designed in livecode but they do not work in the android stand alone version. These keys work fine in other apps I have create with livecode including one in which I have copied the stack & card code from the one that is not working

How do I fix that?

Comment: LiveCode uses the backkey message which is sent to the current card and should work fine, can you post your code. Oops I misread your posting - similar response though as the returnkey and enterkey message is sent to the currently selected object (but there is also the returninfield message if you are trying to use these keys while editing text in a field), anyway, try to be specific and show us your code

Comment: The situation is the similar with the backspacekey message, it's sent to the  object currently holding focus, or if nothing is holding focus to the current card